# Can you execute WHERE clauses in a PostgreSQL stored procedure IF clause?

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, location, database-trigger

So I am creating a trigger that fires after a row in my table called "Users" is updated and I only want it to `pg_notify` if the user's "lat" and "lng" column are within a specified distance from another lat & lng value. I have already created an SQL query with a WHERE clause that selects all users within a certain distance of a given latitude and longitude value, that looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE earth_box(ll_to_earth($1,$2), $3) @> ll_to_earth(lat, lng);
```

The WHERE clause only selects users that have a latitude and longitude within `$3` metres of latitude and longitude points `($1, $2)`. Now I want to make a stored procedure that looks like this utilizing the where clause, i.e. if the changed user's lat and lng point is within a specified radius of a specified lat and lng point, fire a notification :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION notify_on_user_location_update(channel text, specified_lat numeric, specific_lng numeric) RETURNS trigger AS $$
DECLARE
  changed_lat numeric;
  changed_lng numeric;
  specified_radius numeric := 5000;
BEGIN
  IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' OR TG_OP = 'UPDATE' THEN
    changed_lat = NEW.lat;
    changed_lng = NEW.lng;
  ELSE
    changed_lat = OLD.lat;
    changed_lng = OLD.lng;
  END IF;

IF earth_box(ll_to_earth(specified_lat, specified_lng), specified_radius) @> ll_to_earth(changed_lat, changed_lng)
  PERFORM pg_notify(// notification specification here);
ENDIF
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

However, this does not work so its essentially just pseudo code. Can I make this happen somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `IF` is a condition, and in PL it has to use select admitable values. It must have a `THEN` clause and an `END IF;`

In your example it doesn't have an admitable condition and the `THEN` clause is missing. Also, the ENDIF is with space and `;`

But, you can do something like this:

```
IF
    (SELECT count(*)
    FROM users
    WHERE earth_box(ll_to_earth($1,$2), $3) @> ll_to_earth(lat, lng))>0
THEN
    PERFORM pg_notify(// notification specification here);
END IF;
```